# Cqrs + microservices architecture : how to get data from another service

Tags: java, node.js, microservices, cqrs

I'm playing around with setting up a microservices / cqrs architecture for a personal project, and there's one point I don't understand in the "standard" setup.

By standard setup, I mean

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-build-app-using-microservices-and-cqrs-trs/index.html

Say I have an orders service and a pickup points service, and I have a command like "send order summary email".

How should the orders service get the data about the pickup point (eg opening hours etc) that it needs to send the email ? I see 4 possibilities, but there are surely others.

1. The command goes directly to the orders service, and then the orders service queries the pickup points service to get the data.
2. The command goes to the pickup points service, and then pickup points service publishes a new event for orders service with the needed information attached.
3. The command goes directly to the orders service, and the orders service then queries the read-only client-facing database.
4. Merge the 2 services... given that they have no other shared context, this would be a pity...

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

> how to get data from another service

There are two use cases for this.  In your specific case, what you are describing is somewhat akin to [UI Composition](https://particular.net/blog/secret-of-better-ui-composition); you are creating a view that pulls data from two different sources.

Key point #1: the data you are composing is stale -- by the time the email reaches its destination, the truth understood by the services may have changed anyway.  Therefore, there is inherent in the requirements some flexibility about time.

Key point #2: In sending the email, you aren't changing the state of either service at all.  You are just making a copy of some part of it.  Reads are a [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) operation.

Key point #3: Actually sending the email changes the "real world", not the services; it's an activity that can be performed concurrently with the service work.

So what this would normally look like is that one of your read models (probably that of the order service) will support a query that lists orders for which emails will be sent.  Some process, running outside of the service, will periodically query that service for pending emails, query the required read models to compose the message, send it, and finally post a message to the input queue of the order service to share the information that the message was successfully sent.  The order service would see that, and the read model gets updated to indicate that the message has already been sent.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a *process* of sending an *order summary email* to the customer after the *order is completed*.

**In CQRS this is implemented with a Saga/Process manager**.

The idea is that `OrderSummaryEmailSaga` subscribe to the `OrderWasCompleted` event; when such event is fired, the saga queries the `Pickup service` for the information it needs (most probable from a read-model) and then:

1. it builds+sends a complete `SendOrderSummaryEmail` command to the relevant aggregate from the `orders service` or
2. it calls an infrastructure service that, having all the data, it builds an email and send it to the customer
3. or a combination of the previous points, depending on how you want to manage this process

The details are specific to you case, like what domain services (building and formatting the email) or infrastructure services (actual sending of the email using `sendmail` or `postfix` or whatever)  you need to build.